# Kubernetes requesting credentials when installing package with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster in GCP names `foo`.  I created in that cluster a service account for `tiller` and gave it admin rights as follows:

```
kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller
```

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller \
>   --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
>   --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
```

Then I init `Helm` as follows:

```
helm init --service-account tiller
```

Now finally when I try to install my own chart:

```
someserver:helm joe$ helm install onerepo/onechart --name foobar
Error: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

I am already authenticated for cluster `foo` and I can describe all its other resources and service accounts.  Why I cannot deploy using `Helm`?

Comment: Can you confirm tiller-deploy in kube-system is deployed correctly with ServiceAccount tiller:  kubectl describe deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to install helm and use it:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get | bash

kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}' 

helm init --service-account tiller

helm install onerepo/onechart --name foobar
```

Comment: What is `kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}' 
` doing?  I thought the second line there already creates the service account.